# USB device driver installed when mounting a pendrive in Virtualbox

Tags: usb, virtualbox, drivers, usb-flash-drive

Today I inserted a pendrive in my PC and decided to mount it inside Virtualbox. Everything worked, but a message popped up **on my host machine** telling the that the Virtualbox USB driver was succesfully installed (it wasn't the first time I used this pendrive).

Why did this message pop up in my host machine? I was expecting it to pop up inside the guest machine, since it was the first time I mounted it inside there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the first time the device had been connected to the VM, then VirtualBox had to install a USB driver on the host machine to allow it to interface with the host machines USB devices (specifically this device).

Comment: So will it do this every time I connect a new USB device?

Comment: @user1301428 It depends upon the device. It should only happen if it's a new, never before used device.

Comment: But isn't the driver the same for every device?

Comment: @user1301428 Possibly, but the device ID for each device is new.